# Specific return type on AspectJ around call

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I am looking to create around advice on methods with a specific return type. I'm curious if something like that is possible. I have this method for example:

```
@Around("execution(* com.mytest.example.*Resource.*(..))")
public Object restCallMade(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    Response response = null;

    try {
        response = (Response) pjp.proceed();

        // Do other stuff
    } catch (Throwable e) {

    }

    return response;
}
```

However, if possible I would like that this advice only gets called if the return type of the method is Response. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the (fully qualified) type name instead of the joker `*` in the pointcut's method signature:

```java
@Around("execution(org.foo.Response com.mytest.example.*Resource.*(..))")
public Response restCallMade(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = (Response) pjp.proceed();
        // Do other stuff
    } catch (Throwable t) {}
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I was trying that but making the mistake of just putting in Response instead of org.foo.Response.

Comment: So if it works now, please accept and upvote my answer. BTW, the fully qualified names are only necessary in annotation-style aspects. In native AspectJ syntax you can directly use imported class names.